# How to use optional WHERE clause in the SQL?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm trying to fetch the records in a single sql. I would like to use optional WHERE clause in order to do that.
This is what I tried

```
    @Query(value = "select * from Products p where type = 'L' and active = 
1 and ?1 is null or p.pNum =?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Products> findAllParties(String productNumber);
```

This did not work.

I would like to bring all the records when the parameter is empty else would like to bring only the specified product.

How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) as you are mixing `AND` and `OR` .. Also read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Products p where req_param is null or ( type='L' and active=1)
```

Since if req_param is null it will be true for all the rows therefore will bring all records.
if req_param is not empty/null condition "req_param is null" will be false and 
rows will be returned only basis upon "( type='L' and active=1)"

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 separate methods

```
    @Query(value = "select * from Products p where type = 'L' and active = 
1 and ?1 is null or p.pNum =?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Products> findAllParties(String productNumber);

    @Query(value = "select * from Products p ", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Products> findAllParties();
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this....finding a way to achieve it in a single query, infact I have a very big multi joined tables sql so....

Comment: @user3919727, better not avoid writing two methods, because `findAllParties(null)` just looks outright confusing, if you ask me. There either is a filter parameter, or there isn't.

Comment: If you dont like that approach, than use CriteriaAPI

Answer (score 0):

If you want conditionally built queries, use JPA's `Criteria API` for that or Spring's `Specifications API` .